# How to extract the date from Swift String as NSDate?

Tags: ios, swift

My date is `"2017-05-04 13:46:36.0"`. How can I filter only the date from this?

I have used this function:

```
func toDate(dateString : String, dateFormat : String = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")-> NSDate!{
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
  dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
  dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
  let convertedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
  return convertedDate
}

let date = "2017-05-04 13:46:36.0"
```

now I have tried tried to set:

```
lbl.text = String.toDate(dateString: date, dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

But it always returns nil and crashes the app? Why is this happening?

Comment: Try this--
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = /* date_format_you_want_in_string from
                            * http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
                            */
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: /* your_date_string */)

Comment: i have formatted the date as per my requirement isn't there?

Comment: You can write your own , on wich xcode you are ? 
Your have to compose string format for exact date format of string input, and then you can convert to desired form http://nsdateformatter.com here you can find how to write regex for date formater.

Comment: i am on swift 2.Can you review my code.I just need to extract in YYYY-MM-DD format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong Parameter passed

```
var dateString: String = "2017-05-04 13:46:36.0"
var dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
var yourDate: Date? = dateFormatter1.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

> Rule of Date formatter is you must set date format same like your string while you are getting date from string , if mismatch then you will get null

**Swift 2**

```
var dateString: String = "2017-05-04 13:46:36.0"
var dateFormatter1: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
var yourDate: NSDate = dateFormatter1.dateFromString(dateString)
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
print("\(dateFormatter1.stringFromDate(yourDate))")
```

Comment: can you give me your answer in swift2

Comment: @jennysam Just Edited pls check if worked then pls accept answer

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateString = "2017-05-04 13:46:36.0"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: is this for swift 2?

Comment: I checked in Xcode 9(Swift4). Should complie in Swift 3 as well.

Comment: i am on swift 2

Comment: @jennysam: There should be minimal syntax change